# vuetifyjs v-list. If click to item second time item not active. v-model="undefined"

Tags: vuetify.js

I use standard `v-list` component of vuetifyjs. For create menu and show list of items.
But if I click second time the active element is hide. And I don't see active element of menu. It is bad for my menu. Link for example [v-list](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/lists/#examples)

If use pug template below

```js
v-list(dense)
  v-list-item-group(color="success" v-model="selectedItem")
    v-list-item(v-for="(gallery, key) in galleries" :key="key")
      v-list-item-content
        v-list-item-title(v-text="gallery")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solution. It needs `watch` variable and set force index by key of clicked item. If we have 'undefined' set force `data` method

Run examle solution [Solution](https://codepen.io/IvanUkraine/pen/XWgmgoj?editors=1010)

Code below:

```js
<template>
  <div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <v-card max-width="300" >
      <v-list dense>
        <v-list-item-group
          v-model="selectedItem"
          color="primary"
        >
          <v-list-item
            v-for="(item, i) in items"
            :key="i"
          >
            <v-list-item-content @click="setItem(i)">
              <v-list-item-title v-text="item.text"></v-list-item-title>
            </v-list-item-content>
          </v-list-item>
        </v-list-item-group>
      </v-list>
    </v-card>
  </v-app>
</div>
</template>

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  data: () => ({
    index: 0,
    selectedItem: 0,
    items: [
      { text: 'Real-Time'},
      { text: 'Audience' },
      { text: 'Conversions'},
    ],
  }),
  watch: {
    selectedItem() {
      if (typeof this.selectedItem === 'undefined') {
        setTimeout(() => {
          this.selectedItem = this.index;
        }, 500);
      }
    },
  },
  
  methods: {
    setItem(index) {
      this.index = index;
    },
  },
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution would be to disable the v-list-item that has the same index as the selectedItem

```html
<template>
  <div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <v-card max-width="300" >
      <v-list dense>
        <v-list-item-group
          v-model="selectedItem"
          color="primary"
        >
          <v-list-item
            v-for="(item, i) in items"
            :key="i"
            :disabled="i == selectedItem"
          >
            <v-list-item-content>
              <v-list-item-title v-text="item.text"></v-list-item-title>
            </v-list-item-content>
          </v-list-item>
        </v-list-item-group>
      </v-list>
    </v-card>
  </v-app>
</div>
</template>

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  data: () => ({
    selectedItem: 0,
    items: [
      { text: 'Real-Time'},
      { text: 'Audience' },
      { text: 'Conversions'},
    ],
  }),
})
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Set `v-list-item-group` to `mandatory` to avoid undefined